# Black screen reboot when playing certain games

Tags: technical-issues

Recently my PC started to get a black screen reboot in Minecraft if i join a Server or create a world. It not only happens in Minecraft it also happens to  Smite and CS:GO during gameplay.

I tried reinstalled Minecraft, Smite and CS:GO a few times and cleared all remaining Folders but it keeps occuring.

My PC Specs:

- CPU: Intel Core-i7-4790k
- CPU cooler: be quiet shadow rock2
- Video card: MSI GTX 970 Gaming 4G
- PSU: Corsair RM650

Comment: What do you mean by "black screen reboot"? It's not a term I've seen before, and a quick google search does not clarify it either.

Comment: If it occurs in several different games, it is unlikely that the games themselves are at fault. Try reinstalling/updating your hardware drivers for a start.

Comment: Lastly, what OS are you on?

Comment: Without more info, the computer could be overheating. Try using a utility for checking internal temperatures. Specifically the GPU and CPU.

Answer (score 1):

It definitely sounds like you're dealing with more complicated hardware level problems and not directly related to gaming.

Assuming you're using Windows, what you're probably seeing is a stop error (bluescreen) which flickers so fast you can miss it if your system is set to automatically restart on crash.

You could use something like [BluescreenView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html) to review your crash dumps if your system is generating them.  If not, you could turn off automatic restarting using this [guide](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows7/ht/automatic-restart-windows-7.htm).  This will let you at least see what the BSoD is.

But your problem is likely a failing device driver, or physical hardware issue.  You might get better assistance from http://superuser.com